# How to implement a "timely query" using Apache+wsgi?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am new to apache + wsgi programming and I am trying to implement a "email notify" service.

In this service, users will register their email address and interesting game players' name, and web server will timely (for example every 6 hours) query the players' information, if some new matches happen, then send a email to the users who register their email for this player.

Very straight forward approach, but I don't know how to timely invoke the service to query certain informations... I tried to do some Google, but basically I don't even know who should response for this functionality, Apache? or some configuration of mod_wsgi?

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backend task queuing system like Celery and configure periodic tasks.

- http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Do not try and do it as part of the web application.